# Count how many elements present in array2 from array1 with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need some help on this one. I have array1 which is a range which contains X unique GUID.

I want to count how many times any of these unique GUID in array1 have show up in array2, which is a range which contains plenty of GUID.

The result should be one whole number from 1-infinity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use single query formula to get unique list and count the number of accurancies of each element.

Suppose, you have all GUIDs list in Column A. This formula could work:

```
query({A:A,A:A}, 
"select Col1, Count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label Col1 'Guid'")
```

Look for more info about usage of query [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Answer (score 1):

Thre are a number of ways to accomplish this. Here is one:

Let all_guid be the range containing all the GUIDs. And let unique_guid be the range containing the unique ones. To get a count for how many times each unique GUID appear in all you can use the countif function:

```
  =COUNTIF(all_guid;unique_guid)
```

This gives you a range with the count for all GUIDs. You can then apply a filter for the specific one that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Vincent! wierdly I'm getting a result which is not correct, I'm not sure what is going on, it might be counting only the first time it shows. For now, I'm creating another table, and then feeding from there. But I'd like to make it cleaner and not have this intermediate table